# Apart from Religious content, what philosophical doctrines can be found in the Bible?

Tags: ancient-philosophy

today i read the Eclesiastes, and found it quite alike of Stoicism, so i wondered, since the bible is just a compilation of books that are not necessarily related, i wanted to know what other philosophical doctrines can be found and where are they

Comment: See [Ecclesiastes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastes#Composition): "The presence of Persian loan-words and Aramaisms points to a date no earlier than about 450 BCE, while the latest possible date for its composition is 180 BCE, when the Jewish writer Ben Sira quotes from it. The dispute as to whether Ecclesiastes belongs to the Persian or the Hellenistic periods (i.e., the earlier or later part of this period) revolves around the degree of Hellenization (influence of Greek culture and thought) present in the book.  1/2

Comment: "Scholars arguing for a Persian date (c. 450–330 BCE) hold that there is a complete lack of Greek influence; those who argue for a Hellenistic date (c. 330–180 BCE) argue that it shows internal evidence of Greek thought and social setting." *Conclusion*: we have to consider historical facts, based on date (not easy to define) and possible influences. 2/2

Comment: Some would say the Biblical philosophy is 'non-dualism'. This is the philosophy of the book 'A Course in Miracles' which (some would say) fleshes out the Biblical teachings.in modern terms. The problem is that to see this interpretation one probably has to already know the philosophy. The non-canonical literature (Nag Hammadi, Thomas, the Desert Fathers, Dionysius, Eckhart et al) present this philosophy more clearly.